# Find array if it is subset of another array

Tags: java, arrays, subset

This function should return true only if the parameter object is a subset of the calling object but it always returns true. How to fix it?

```
    public boolean contains(FileCollection other) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        for (i = 0; i<other.files.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j<this.files.length; j++) {
                if ((other.files[i]).equals((this.files[j]))) //this refers to the equals method defined in File class
                    break;
            }
            if (j==this.files.length) 
                return false;
        }
        return true;//this method is in FileCollection class
    }
```

Comment: @vincrichaud it is very clear- I said it always returns true. But the answer needs to be true only if the parameter object is a subset of the calling object

Comment: Now it is, thanks for the edit

Comment: Your inner loop exits when `j = this.files.length + 1`

Comment: @vincrichaud then what should it be?

Comment: The loop exits when the condition is no more matches : when `j = this.files.length +1 `.In your code, you consider it exits when `j = this.files.length`. To make your code okay, you just have to change the if condition to the same as the for condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only this answer works for me: (Credit to @Joop Eggen for the Comparator part)

```
public boolean contains(FileCollection other) {
    Comparator<File> comparator = new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File lhs, File rhs) {
            int cmp = lhs.getBase().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.getBase());
            if (cmp == 0) {
               cmp = lhs.getExtension().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.getExtension());
            }
            if (cmp == 0) {
               cmp = Long.compare(lhs.getSize(), rhs.getSize());
            }
            if (cmp == 0) {
               cmp = Long.compare(lhs.getPermissions(), rhs.getPermissions());
            }
            return cmp;
        }
    };
    Arrays.sort(this.files, comparator);
    Arrays.sort(other.files, comparator); //THIS AND THE COMPARATOR SORT THE ARRAYS BASED ON ALL FILE ATTRIBUTES    
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    if (this.files.length<other.files.length)
        return false;
    while (i<other.files.length && j<this.files.length) {
        if (!(this.files[j].equals(other.files[i])))
            j++;
        else {
            j++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    if (i<other.files.length)
        return false;
    else
        return true; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

(Since you didn't explicitly express what the data type of the array elements is, I'll assume it's `File`, inferred from comments.)

If you don't mind converting between data structures, maybe converting your arrays (temporarily) to Collections is the most simple way. For example, converting to `List`:

```
/* @param other
 * @return true if the calling object contains
 * all files in the parameter object, false otherwise
 */
public boolean contains(FileCollection other) {
    List<File> myList = Arrays.asList(this.files);
    List<File> otherList = Arrays.asList(other.files);
    return myList.containsAll(otherList);
}
```

Based on your clarify of what to be considered as "contains" when duplicated items are allowed, I'd say you need to count the number of existence for each element. Here is how:

Based on the answer of @Eritrean , you can get and store the count to a map. I made modifications to check the count too:

```
public boolean contains(FileCollection other) {
    Map<File,Integer> otherFrequency = Arrays.stream(other.files)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v->1,Integer::sum));

    Map<File,Integer> thisFrequency  = Arrays.stream(this.files) 
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v->1,Integer::sum));

    if (thisFrequency.entrySet().containsAll(otherFrequency).entrySet()) {
        for (File entry : otherFrequency.entrySet()) {
            if (thisFrequency.get(entry) < otherFrequency.get(entry))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Was writing exactly the same suggestion :-)

Comment: Change `List` into `List<File>`

Comment: it is always returning false

Comment: @BhushanOza So are there any duplicated elements in each array?

Comment: @renyuneyun yes it can have duplicated items

Comment: @RobertKock But we won't know the exact type, only shown in the comment ;p

Comment: @BhushanOza And how do you define "contains" when `this.files` has one `A` while `other.files` has two `A`s? Is that `true` or `false` based on you needs?

Comment: @renyuneyun The files have many attributes like name, size, etc. that have to be equal for the File array to be a subset. That's why I have used my File.equals() method in the question

Comment: @BhushanOza Yes I'm aware of that, and the `containsAll()` methods uses `equals()` internally. But the problem is not there. The problem is what do *you* define as "contains", when `this.files` has one element `A` while `other.files` has two exactly the same `A`s (from `equals()`'s concern)? Should this be `true` or `false` from your perspective?

Comment: @renyuneyun that should be false

Comment: @renyuneyun You're right. I edited the answer once again.

Comment: @BhushanOza Since there is still no answers targeting the duplicated scenario, I added that to my answer. Hope this solves your problem. You'll need the count stored in a Map, unless you sorted the list in advance (for which you can use `rightest_index_of_this_element - leftest_index_of_this_element` as the count).

Comment: @renyuneyun the Map code gives me 2 errors:
1.`no suitable method found for containsAll(Map<File,Integer>)
        if (thisFrequency.entrySet().containsAll(otherFrequency).entrySet()) {
                                    ^
    method Collection.containsAll(Collection<?>) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; Map<File,Integer> cannot be converted to Collection<?>)`

2.`FileCollection.java:16: error: incompatible types: Entry<File,Integer> cannot be converted to File
            for (File entry : otherFrequency.entrySet()) {`
                                                     ^

Comment: @renyuneyun
I fixed the 1st error- the brackets were aligned wrongly

Comment: @renyuneyun
The 2nd error has been fixed by changing File to Entry

Answer (score 2):

For `other.files` contains `this.files` to hold, every `this.file` must be in `other.files`.

```
    for (int j = 0; j < this.files.length; j++) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < other.files.length; i++) {
            if (other.files[i].equals(this.files[j])) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) { 
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

Not knowing the class of `files`, probably you can do:

```
    for (String file : this.files) {
        boolean found = false;
        for (String otherFile : other.files) {
            if (otherFile.equals(file)) {
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) { 
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

Or even

```
    for (String file : this.files) {
        boolean found = other.files.indexOf(file) != -1;
        if (!found) { 
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

There are nicer datastructures that speed things up, and have predefined methods for things like `contains`.

---

***With duplicates***

```
    Comparator<File> comparator = new Comparator<File>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(File lhs, File rhs) {
            int cmp = lhs.getBase().compareIgnoreCase(rhs.getBase());
            if (cmp == 0) {
               cmp = lhs.getExtension().compareIgnoreCase(rhs.getExtension());
            }
            if (cmp == 0) {
               cmp = Long.compare(lhs.getSize(), rhs.getSize());
            }
            return cmp;
        }
    };

    Arrays.sort(this.files, comparator);
    Arrays.sort(other.files, comparator);
    int otherI = 0;
    for (File file : this.files.length) {
        boolean found = false;
        while (otherI < other.files.length) {
            int comparison = comparator.compare(other.files[otherI], file);
            ++otherI;
            if (comparison >= 0) {
                found = comparison == 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) { 
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
```

By sorting both arrays you can synchronize the comparison at locations in both arrays. The above handles duplicates.

Comment: Using your first answer, one of tests fail- when both arrays have a duplicate each. It should be true but it comes out as false

Comment: In that case sorting makes sense, then counting & checking duplicates is easier. `Arrays.sort`.

Comment: Arrays.sort() does not work. The File class has many attributes like name, size, etc. It gives ClassCastException

Comment: the Arrays.sort() raises ClassCastException

Comment: I saw your comment too late; added a Comparator. Not sure about the class File, neither what field to compare.

Comment: The File class has an equals() method. That can be used to compare

Comment: Unfortunately one also needs a sort order, `<`. Is there not a way to have the full path as String, or the nodeid on linux?

Comment: One could compare on _all_ attributes, name, when 0, on size, when 0 on ... . If you have the source of `equals` you can see what makes two Files equal.

Comment: Here is the equals method code:
`return (this.getBase().equalsIgnoreCase(other.getBase()) && this.getExtension().equalsIgnoreCase(other.getExtension()) && this.getSize()==other.getSize() && this.getPermissions()==other.getPermissions())`

Comment: You can turn that in a nested comparison {-1, 0, 1} using also `getBase().compareIgnoreCase(...)`. As long as the comparison remains 0, continue with the next attribute.

Comment: can you please edit your answer to include that? as I don't know how to do that

Comment: the comparator line gives this error: '<>' cannot be used with anonymous classes

Comment: Changed it to `<File>`. In the newest java that would be no longer be an error I assumed.

Comment: thanks for the help, but it still fails that one test

Comment: Thanks for the patience anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the @renyuneyun suggestion to convert your arrays into Lists you could also make use of the `String` `contains` method

```
public boolean contains(FileCollection other) {
String myList = Arrays.toString(this.files);
String otherList = Arrays.toString(other.files);
return myList.contains(otherList);
}
```

Of course both of these suggestions are not the optimum solutions from the complexity point of view, but are for sure the shortests :)

Answer (score 1):

What about using a map with File as key and frequency as value:

```
public boolean contains(FileCollection other) {
    Map<File,Integer> otherFrequency = Arrays.stream(other.files)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v->1,Integer::sum));

    Map<File,Integer> thisFrequency  = Arrays.stream(this.files) 
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v->1,Integer::sum));

    return thisFrequency.entrySet().containsAll(otherFrequency.entrySet());
}
```